# Grep words before and after match?

Tags: regex, bash, grep

Is there a simple solution to also extract one word before and one word after along with the matched word? For example, assuming the following text

```
... put returns between paragraphs ...
... the function returns void ...
```

the search for `returns` should return

```
put returns between
function returns void
```

I am not a bash expert, but could put together the following

```
grep -o -P "(?:[a-zA-Z'-]+[^a-zA-Z'-]+){1}returns(?:[^a-zA-Z'-]+[a-zA-Z'-]+){1}" TEXT.FILE
```

but not sure if this catches all.

Comment: You can use `grep -oP '(\w+\W+)?returns(\W+\w+)?'`

Comment: Is there a case when the text "returns" does not have a word before or after?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew note there is no need to use `-P` for this: `-E` suffices.

Comment: @fedorqui: does it have any impact on performance?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, `-P` is for `P`erl regexps, which are more expensive than the `E`xtended ones. Of course, for a tiny file this shouldn't matter at all but it is good practice to "just" use the needed extension. Also, `-E` is specified by POSIX, while `-P` _is highly experimental and grep  -P  may  warn  of unimplemented features_ (from `man grep`).

Comment: @fedorqui: I do not think there should be any difference when using such basic patterns. Is there any link to `grep` performance tests with identical, simple PCRE and extended patterns? I could not find any :(

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Well, as always it is a matter of using resources as they are needed: we can say `cat file | grep '1'` or `grep '1' file`. They are the same and the performance won't differ much, but it is good to know that `grep` alone can read the file. In this case, opening the Perl Regexp engine sounds like too much when the Extended can already handle it. Also, note the POSIX part I mentioned later in my comment, which is also relevant.

Comment: @Wiktor I too had my doubts that it should be any slower to use `-P` so I just ran a pretty unscientific test `time grep -E '\w+' <(seq 1000000) > /dev/null` and it took ~0.55s, whereas the same using `-P` took ~0.85s.

Comment: @TomFenech: Thank you, so that means using the right regex flavor *is* of importance with `grep`.

Comment: @Wiktor I guess it'd be worth looking into it in a little more depth before drawing that conclusion but it certainly looks like it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just tell `grep` to match only `<word> + returns + <word>`:

```
$ grep -Eo '\w+ returns \w+' file
put returns between
function returns void
```

Comment: `'\w+ returns \w+'` won't return matches if a word before or after is missing (start/end of string).

Comment: ... Or if punctuation interferes.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yep, I just focused on the basic example for a beginning. Probably `(\w+ )?` on both sides would make it more robust.

Comment: @fedorqui That would then match if another word contained the string `returns`

Comment: @123 Sorry, didn't realise you where talking about `(\w+ )?`

Comment: ... Or there are more than one blank between words.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
grep -oP '\w*\s*\breturns\b\s*\w*' file
```

#### Input

```
... put returns between paragraphs ...
... the function returns void ...
returns void 123r
123 4 void returns
123returns
```

#### Output

```
put returns between
function returns void
returns void
void returns
```

Will match if no word before or after returns

Answer (score 0):

To match `returns` with *optional* word at the left/right:

```
grep -o -P '(?:\p{L}+\s+)?returns(?:\s+\p{L}+)?' file
```

where `\p{L}` is a [Unicode category](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) for a "letter".

To match `returns` with *required* words at the left and right:

```
grep -o -P '(?:\p{L}+\s+)returns(?:\s+\p{L}+)' file
```